# How to get the Images to display using v-for?

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, for-in-loop

I used v-for on an array (named items) which contains name and url of respective images but when i give the image URL of an individual to the img tag it shows nothing.

> This is code to display Images

```html
    <template>
    <main>
      <div v-bind:key="item" v-for="item in items">
        <img src=item.url alt="No Image" title="Order Now" />
        <section>{{item.name}}</section>
      </div>
    </main>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
    name: 'ShowCase',
    data() {
      return{
        items:[
          {
            name:"Doritos Nacho Cheese", 
            url:"../assets/dnc.jpg"
          },
          {
            name:"Kurkure Hyderbadi Hungama", 
            url:"../assets/kkhh.jpg"
          }, 
        ]
      }
    }
```

![**check this image (image doesn't show up in webpage)][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're not using VueJS binding to tell your images their `src`, so instead of a URL, they receive the string `item.url`

Just replace

```html
<img src="item.url" alt="No Image" title="Order Now" />
```

With

```html
<img :src="item.url" alt="No Image" title="Order Now" />
```

And it should work. The `:` (alias of `v-bind:`) before `src` tells VueJS it's a dynamic attribute and it must look for its value into the component context.

**N.B:** Don't forget the double quotes around `item.url`, they're mandatory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it's not working....

Comment: Please edit your post and add your current code to see what is missing.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the double quotes when binding the attribute. Remember, `:` works just like `v-bind:`.

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
   <img
      :src="item.url"
      :alt="item.name"
      title="Order Now!"
   />

   <section>{{ item.name }}</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's still not working

Comment: You need to places your images into the folder `public/assets`, then you can change your URLs to `assets/dnc.jpg`, `assets/kkhh.jpg`, etc. More informations about static assets in Vue.JS can be found [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#disable-index-generation).

Comment: Thanks it worked i changed the location of image

Comment: Happy to be helpful. Remember to mark the question as answered.